# How far a 220V AC line should be placed to avoid EMI?

Tags: ac, emc

In my apartment I have a control panel for a solar water heater, this panel provides AC for a water pump and an electric heater approx. 2500 W combined. Unfortunately this AC line is very close alongside temperature and water level sensors' wires, so when I turn on either one of them, the temperature reading starts fluctuating. How far the AC line needs to be placed from the sensors' lines?

Comment: It's impossible to determine from your description how susceptible those connections are and hence how far the two cables need to be apart to minimize cross-talk.

Comment: Depends how long they are and how sensitive they are. So, ... far enough.

Answer (score 1):

With a good design the 2 cables can run touching parallel alongside several 100m.
Good design meaning any or a combination of

- shielded sensor cable
- Twisted pair sensor cable
- differential sensor signal
- isolated sensor signal
- filtered input of sensor signal
- high level of sensor signal

So unless you know the details, you'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need minimum crosstalk, or zero crosstalk. You just need acceptably low crosstalk.

Verify the voltage across temperature sensor is just a few volts. 
Use a DVM, first on AC and then on DC; if you observe more than a few volts,
do not proceed down this path any further.
Turn OFF the power.
Try installing (when power is OFF) a 1uF ceramic capacitor across sensor wires.
You can install the 1uF right at the control-box.
Turn the power back on. Proceed with your evaluation.

No guarantees about this. All risks are yours.

Why might this work? Because there is no conductive path between the AC wires and the sensor wires, thus only spikes and other trash get coupled, with either magnetic or electric field fluctuations (or both). The 1uF requires much more charge be injected to cause an upset, and should reduce the induced voltage errors proportionately. If 100pF is your present wiring, then 1uF may reduce the errors by 100pF/1uF or 10,000x smaller. Your RTN or GND wiring may limit that possible 10,000X to something much smaller.